# Woocommerce get all shipping methods configured

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im building a WooCommerce plugin that add some features (basically new fields) to checkout;
these fields should appear based on the selected shipping method on checkout, and the association is to be made by the admin in the plugin setting page (the admin will choose for which shipping methods the features will be available).
So in my setting page i need a way to list all the shipping methods configured in the shop
i tried with

```
WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods()
```

but it returns a list of configurable shipping methods (not the one configured)
i wasnt able to find a function the gives me an array of the configured method that includes:
zone - type - name - cost
any hint?

Answer (score 0):

i just discovered i need to get the zones before:

```
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

        foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone) {

            echo "<b>" . $the_zone['zone_name'] . "</b><br>";
            foreach ($the_zone['shipping_methods'] as $value) {
                //print_r($value);
                echo $value->title . " ( " . $value->method_title . " - " . $value->cost . ")" . $value->id . ":" . $value->instance_id;
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
```